# Writing a bingo game in Java, having trouble

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I got a project where I need to create a bingo game that is meant to be played in the CMD/Terminal. I'm having trouble replacing the numbers in the 2D array(if the player input matches the number in any of the 2 cards, it gets replaced with " XX" then continues the game with the numbers marked " XX") and check for if user has gotten all the numbers in a line and then display something along the lines of "Bingo, Player "name" wins!"(There will be 2 player cards only). I also cant figure out how I can stop user from entering already crossed out/duplicated numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class demno {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int call, r = 0, c = 0;   /* For the player to input bingo numbers. 
                            To declare row and column globally for later use. */

        // Initiate card 1 numbers
        int[][] card1 = { {24, 2,  8, 1,  25},
                          {12, 16, 7, 17, 15},
                          {5, 6, 20, 19, 13 },
                          {14, 23, 22, 4, 3 },
                          {10, 18, 11, 21, 9} };
        // Initiate card 2 numbers
        int[][] card2 = { {24, 21, 17, 15, 6},
                          {10, 3, 8, 18, 20  },
                          {14, 7, 16, 12, 5  },
                          {25, 23, 13, 19, 11},
                          {22, 4, 9, 1, 2    } };


        // Player 1's card
        System.out.println("Player 1's card:");
        for (r=0; r<card1.length; r++) {
            for(c=0;c<card1.length; c++){
                if (10 > card1[r][c] ){
                    System.out.print(" "+ card1[r][c] +" ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print(card1[r][c] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        // End Player 1's card
        
        System.out.print('\n');
        // Player 2's card
        System.out.println("Player 2's card:");
        for (r=0; r<card2.length; r++) {
            for(c=0;c<card2.length; c++){
                if (10 > card2[r][c]) {
                    System.out.print(" " + card2[r][c] + " ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print(card2[r][c] + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        // End Player 2's card

        // User input for bingo number
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Game Host call (0 to exit): ");
            call = sc.nextInt();
            sc.close();
        // Checks user input for errors or if player want's to exit.
        if (call >25) {
            System.out.println("The number must be between 1 to 25, please call again! ");
            System.out.print("Game Host call (0 to exit): ");
            call = sc.nextInt();
            sc.close();
        }else if (call == 0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace a value in an array with `array[0] = "XX"`. So in your case it would be `card2[r][c] = "XX"`.

To be sure every number is used one time an easy solution would be an ArrayList. So you can use it like

```
List<Integer> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//  when number was used
usedNumbers.add(call);

//check if already used
boolean alreadyUsed = usedNumbers.contains(call);
```

Another tip:

```java
for (r = 0; r < card2.length; r++) {
    for(c = 0; c < card2.length; c++) {
       ...
    }
}
```

only works if the number of arrays in `card2` equals the number of items in each list. If not you will get an `OutOfBoundsException`.
The correct way is to use the length of the inner array for `c`:

```java
for (r = 0; r < card2.length; r++) {    
    for(c = 0; c < card2[r].length; c++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

To implement the game logic you have to take the following steps:

- After Scan of numbers check if player A has a match.
- If there is a match give him a point (increase an int variable maybe?).
- Then replace the match with XX.
- Same for player B.
- If one of the point variable == 5 print the winner and stop application

Comment: I'm not too sure where to put the arraylist? Should I put it on top of the user input which starts right after the cards are displayed.

Comment: yes, the initialisation has to be before the first usage. So add the list to the top of the method, the check  when the next input is scanned and the add directly under the check.

Answer (score 0):

Keep things separate.  Updating the card and checking for victory are two different things.  Define separate methods for doing them.

```
private void updateCard(int[][] card, int ball) { ... }
private boolean isWinner(int[][] card) { ... }
```

Because you are modeling the card as an `int[][]` you obviously cannot put a "XX" in it because that is a `String`.  That's OK.  When a ball matches the card cell, replace the value number with a marker that is not a legit value (e.g. assuming balls range from 1 to 25, you can use -1 as the marker).  Create a method that will print the card but will inspect the value in the cell and replace it with "XX" in the output if the marker is encountered.

```
private void printCard(int[][] card) { ... }
```

Bingo is classically played with a series of balls being drawn from a basket.  There is one ball for each possible number.  Therefore you cannot drawn the same number more than once.  You could emulate this by creating a basket of numbers.  When the user enters a number, remove it from the basket.  If it is not in the basket then it is not a valid number and the user must enter a different number.

```
public class Game {
  private Set<Integer> basket = new HashSet<Integer>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialize(basket); // put all the balls are in the basket
    ...
  }
```

Then you can do something like this to make sure a ball hasn't already been drawn.

```
private int drawBall(Set<Integer> basket) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(basket, "basket cannot be null");
  if (basket.isEmpty()) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("There are no more balls in the basket");
  }
  int ball = getUserDraw();
  while (basket.contains(ball)) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, that ball has already been drawn");
    ball = getUserDraw();
  }
  basket.remove(ball);
  return ball;
}
```